# OK button on the captured picture with system camera not working in one plus 6T with Android Pie

Tags: android, android-camera

In the system camera application accessed via `new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)` the OK button isn't working. Other buttons such as reset and cancel are working.

For other devices including other android Pie devices, it is working normally. Logcat shows the following error:

`E/ReviewScreenImpl: onClickOKButton() - Fail to decode captured picture`

This is most probably a device specific software issue since this issue has happened suddenly.

Comment: sreejith, did you find the what was the issue

Comment: I am also facing the same issue, is there any solutions for this?

Comment: If your targetSdkVersion is 29, you need to opt-out of scoped storage by adding android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" in the application tag of your app's manifest file. For Reference check this link: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/use-cases#opt-out-scoped-storage

Comment: any update? still not working for me

Comment: This worked for me

File sd_directory = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
return File.createTempFile(new_name, ".jpg", sd_directory);
removed for: File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES); return new File(storageDir, imageFileName + ".jpg");